# Generate kwargs for Django bootstrap_field

Tags: django, django-bootstrap4

I'm trying to auto generate a list of fields for a Django form with the bootstrap4 package.

I'm defining the kwargs in a dict, and want to loop through the fields and apply any kwargs to the bootstrap_field tag that comes with bootstrap4.

Data

```
data = [
    {
        "name": "school_1",
        "args": {
            "show_label": True,
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "school_2",
        "args": {
            "show_label": False,
        },
    },
]
```

Template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {% bootstrap_field field field|get_kwargs:data %}
{% endfor %}
```

Template filter:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
@register.filter
def get_kwargs(formfield, data):
    item = next((item for item in data if item["name"] == formfield.name), None)
    if item:
        return item.get('args'):
    return None
```

The issue is the bootstrap_field tag is using what the filter returns as an arg, not a kwarg. Is there anything I can do or do I need to replace bootstrap_field?

Error `render_field() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

```
args    (<django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x10f834240>,
 {'show_label': True})
kwargs  {}
```

Comment: try `{% bootstrap_field field kwargs=field|get_kwargs:data %}`

Comment: @dirkgroten it will pass `{'kwargs': {'key': 'value'}}` to `bootstrap_field`

Comment: i was afraid so. I don't think it's possible like this, if I were you I would create a template filter that calls `bootstrap_field` in order to pass the data as `**kwargs`.

Comment: @dirkgroten that's what i was thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think kwargs unpacking is not available in django templating language. What you can do is make your filter render actual field for you like this

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register
from bootstrap4.templatetags.bootstrap4 import bootstrap_field


@register.filter
def get_kwargs(formfield, data):
    item = next((item for item in data if item["name"] == formfield.name), None)
    kwargs = item.get('args') or {}
    return bootstrap_field(formfield, **kwargs)
```

and in template just do

```
{{ field|get_kwargs:data }}
```

Ps: you can change name of `get_kwargs` to something more meaningful if you implement it this way (like `render_field`)